# HTML - How to connect two dropdown and make the second one clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, clickable

I connected two dropdown menus using this code:

```
<script>
function populate(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
        var optionArray = ["|","camaro|Camaro","corvette|Corvette","impala|Impala"];
    } else if(s1.value == "Dodge"){
        var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
    } else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
        var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}



</script>
```

and

```
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select>
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
```

now I want to make the options in the second dropdown menu (models) clickable. To another sites for example : the page of each model. All that happen in the same page inside one

I am using HTML , CSS, Java script ...

Comment: Would you elaborate more on the meaning of "in the second drop-down menu (models) clickable"?

Comment: i mean that when you choose any option of the second drop-down menu .. a site will open in a specific iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding options to second dropdown using the populate function in script.
And yes it will be clickable as it is a dropdown select options. If you want to trigger function on second drpdown click then you can add onchange like you have added in first.

Comment: i found this code so i dont know alot about it or how to add onChange for the second dropdown.. so if you can provide the rest of code i will glad ...

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood, you are looking something like this:

```
<select id="slct1" name="slct1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
    <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select><br>
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
```

I would rethink the Javascript part, and I would use jquery for accessing the DOM:

```
// you can update this object to be as big as you want
var OPTION_ARRAY = {
    chevy: {
        camaro: {
            value: 'camaro',
            key: 'Camaro',
        },
        corvette: {
            value: 'corvette',
            key: 'Corvette',
        },
    },
    dodge: {
        avenger: {
            value: 'avenger',
            key: 'Avenger',
        }
    },
};

function cleanSelect2() {
    $('#slct2').find('option').remove().end();
}

function fillSelect2(value) {
    var values = OPTION_ARRAY[value.toLowerCase()];
    var $mySelect = $('#slct2');
    for (var element in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
            $mySelect
                .append($('<option></option>')
                .attr('value', values[element].value)
                .text(values[element].key));
        }
    }
}

$('#slct1').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();
    cleanSelect2();
    fillSelect2(value);
});
```

Comment: where i can add the site for each choice which will open in specific iframe ?